# Program keeps on crashing

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I don't know why this program doesn't work:

```
 char syze;
 printf("Please enter your desired size (Choose from S,M,L,XL)\n");
 scanf("%s", &syze);

 if(syze =='S')
 {printf("Available");}


 else if(syze =='M')
     {printf("Available");}
 else if(syze =='L')
     {printf("Available");}
 else if(strcmp(syze,"XL")==0)
     {printf("Available");}
 else
     {printf("Please enter a valid character");}
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
 scanf("%s", &syze);
```

in your code, `size` is of type `char` and you should be using `%c` format specifier to scan the input.

If you use `%s` format specifier to scan the input for a `char`, essentially you'll be overrunning the allocated memory thereby creating [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Then,

```
 strcmp(syze,"XL")
```

is also wrong, as [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) needs a (`const`)`char *` as both the arguments, and you're passing a `char` as the first one. You can simply make use of the equality operator, `==` to compare a `char`.

Finally, a `char` will never be able to hold `"XL"`.

**Solution:** If you need to have `"XL"` as one of the inputs, you may want to change `syze` to an array, like

```
 char syze[3] = {0};
```

or likewise. In that case, you can keep the `scanf()` as

```
scanf("%2s", syze);
```

and compare your inputs using `strcmp()`.

Comment: Please suggest a code in which i use not only S,M,L but also XL.

Comment: So, strcmp compares strings stored in arrays, but not in char variable?

Comment: @FahadSaleem basically, yes. It compares _strings_.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in `strcmp(syze,"XL")==0`. You can't compare a `char` to a string `XL`.  Use only `X` for that choice and compare the same as the others `if(syze =='X')`.

You have another problem in `scanf("%s", &syze);`. Use `%c` to scan a `char`:

```
 scanf("%c", &syze);`
```

If you want to keep using the choice "XL", you should declare `syze` as `char syze[3]` and compare all choices using `strcmp`.

Comment: what var can i use then?

Comment: Use `X` instead of `XL` for choice

Comment: It works that. Already tried it... But it's important to use XL

Comment: if it's important than use the type `char syze[3]` and compare all choices using `strcmp`

Comment: @bigOTHER `char syze[2]` won't be sufficient for `"XL"`.